# How to send image file in the body of the email

Tags: android, image, android-intent

I know this question is already ask in the stack overflow, and I looked around them but don't get any clue. Actually I have written code for sending an image file as an attachment to my mail and its working fine. The code I used for sending an image file as an attachment is shown below. Can anyone tell me what are the changes I need to do to send the image file in the body of mail? Any clue will be helpful.

**Code for sending the image as an attached file**

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("content://" + CachedFileProvider.AUTHORITY + "/" + fileNameArray.get(position));
        
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("image/png");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send email"));
```

Comment: You got any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

only work in device not in android emulator..

http://blogingtutorials.blogspot.com/2010/12/send-email-with-attached-file-in.html

Comment: Sending image as an attach file is already done by me..have u go through my question..its clearly written there that i want to send my imageFile in the body of my mail not as attchement.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following intent:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
emailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] 
{"me@gmail.com"}); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, 
"Test Subject"); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
"go on read the emails"); 
Log.v(getClass().getSimpleName(), "sPhotoUri=" + Uri.parse("file:/"+ sPhotoFileName));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+ sPhotoFileName));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Comment: But this will send file as an attchment, which i already do it. I want to send image in the body of mail not as attachement